# pstricks generated image doesn't fit into page.

Tags: pstricks, pst-tree

I have a pstricks image in a document like

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-eps}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\begin{document}%
\begin{TeXtoEPS}%
\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,-1.50)(7.5,3)%
\normalsize%

 % tree here, sorry but confidential and big.
\end{pspicture}
\end{TeXtoEPS}
 \end{document}
```

And I generate the ps using `latex; dvips to ps`. But it is too big to fit on the page, only the leftmost part is shown. How to make it fit??? Thanks.

Comment: You should present an example that demonstrates your problem. At the moment there is no problem with your code sample. Please construct the most simple example that reproduces the described misbehaviour, a so called [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). Replace confidential content with dummy text.

Comment: I imagine the problem is that somewhere in your document you have used `\psset{<something>}`, so your current picture is being drawn off the page. Have a look at the `\setwindow` command that I define in [scaling-a-pst-3dplot-to-fit-a-beamer-frame](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33032/scaling-a-pst-3dplot-to-fit-a-beamer-frame)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `\resizebox` from the `graphicx` package

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}%

\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,-1.50)(7.5,3)% not really needed for a tree
\normalsize%

 % tree here, sorry but confidential and big.
\end{pspicture}%
}
 \end{document}
```

By the way: a tree does not need the `pspicture` environment

Comment: I used scaledbox... which is similar...

Comment: `scalebox` makes only sense if you _really_ know which factor for scaling should used.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\psset{unit=0.5cm}` before command `\begin{pspicture}` to scale entire picture by changing the value of the unit. Obviously 0.5cm above was randomly choosen. You sholuld play little bit to figure out which scale works for you.

Comment: I tried `\psset{}` but it affected only part of the figure. the issue is that I am not the only one writing it, so didn't want to change the content. I used `\usepackage{graphicx} %\scalebox .... \scalebox{\myscale}{ \begin{pspicture} % picture data here \end{pspicture} }` Then used a ps tool to get a `eps` figure with accurate bounding box.

Comment: this was supposed to be my answer... I should have said it solved the problem.